# Why my mute command is not working - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

my mute command isn't muting the user after typing the command.
My code:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await user.edit(reason=reason, mute=True)
    embed = discord.Embed(description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(user, ctx.message.author),
                          color=0xff00f6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

error - Target user is not connected to voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to mute a user in a text channel. You have to create a `Muted` role and add that role to the user:

```py
@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason):
    guild = ctx.guild
    if not get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted"):  # Create muted role if it does not exist.
        role_perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, speak=False)
        await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=role_perms)
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.add_roles(muted_role, reason=reason)

    await ctx.send(f"{member} was muted by {ctx.message.author}\n**Reason**: {reason}.")
```

Comment: Move Muted role to top of your server’s roles and make sure user you’re testing on does not have Administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use permissions for admin commands

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```